# Android Web view swiping for Arabic version

Tags: android, webview, swipe

I am developing E pub reader,It works fine with English version with swiping (right to left for next page),(left to right for previous page),

but,for Arabic version we have to change the swiping from (left to right for next page),(right to left for previous page) how to do that?

I am using the android web View with JavaScript, Css